# C++ Linker Error (Unresolved External) when linking to /clr DLL

Tags: c++, dll, linker, clr

I have a DLL with the /clr option ON. I have the following declaration in my DLL:

```
int __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl  test();
```

Also, I have a console with /clr option ON. And have the following declaration on my main.cpp file:

```
int __declspec(dllimport) __cdecl  test();
```

I added the Reference to the DLL project on the property settings of my console application. But I still get unresolved externals from the compiler about the test function.

I managed to compile by manually adding a reference to the lib file generated by the compiler. But then I can't hit breakpoints inside the DLL functions (it says the source code is different from the original version or the symbols have not been loaded...)

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you actually define `test()` anywhere (as opposed to just declaring it)? Could you in fact be linking to an old version of the lib?

Comment: Yes I did define test in a cpp file. I doubt I am linking to an old version of the lib because even when I clean the whole solution, the problem persists.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. Is the DLL actually managed (ie can you simply remove the /clr option)?

Comment: I found this question when I ran into the same problem.  My case may be the same as yours, or maybe not.  In any case, the solution I need may help you out.  Here is my scenario:

I work on a large legacy system (10+ EXEs, 50+ DLLs) - all of which were written in C++ up until about 2005, when we started migrating some pieces to C#, using C++/CLR as interop.

Now, it would be nice if I could simply go through all of my C++ code and set the compiler option to /CLR, fix the bugs and ship a mix of C# and C++/CLR - with no 'pure' unmanaged code left.

Comment: IF that worked, I could migrate the C++/CLR implementations to make use of the .NET framework.  I could add managed (CLR) interfaces to the DLLs.  Eventually, I could even replace the C++/CLR code with C# (much easier to work on).  BUT IT DOESN'T WORK.

Comment: The core of the issue appears to be how Visual Studio links dependent projects.  If any C++ or C++/CLR project references a C++ DLL project, the DLL's export LIB is automatically linked into the caller.  Same thing if a C++ project references a C++/CLR DLL project.  BUT when a C++/CLR project references a C++/CLR DLL, then only the managed API of the DLL is made available, because the export LIB is not linked.

Answer (score 0):

If your DLL doesn't use any managed functionality, simply remove the `/clr` option from that project and recompile. If you still get the errors, it's probably related to the references in the console application.

If the DLL use managed functionality, what you need is instead like so:

**DLL**:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

namespace Test1
{
    public ref class Test2
    {
        public:
            static int test()
            {
                return 1;
            }
    };
}
```

**Console app**:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = Test1::Test2::test();        
    std::cout << i << std::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: My DLL have some managed and some unmanaged classes. Right now I can't port my unmanaged classes to managed counterparts. I use this DLL in a lot of scenarios. When I link this library with a unmanaged console app, i got those linker error(except when I manually link with the generated lib file but then I can't break into the lib when debugging). When I try this library with a managed console, it works without problems...

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho I'm a little confused. So the console app you're having trouble with is unmanaged, yet you're compiling it with the `/clr` flag? Are you sure marked the method in question as unmanaged with a `#pragma unmanaged` or `#pragma managed(push, off)`? Regardless, you should be able to link, but how you go about doing it depends on the specifics (and, yes, you may need to manually add the `.lib` file).

Comment: No I didn't do that. Why do I need to do that? Can't the compiler know the method is unmanaged by looking at the __declspec(dllexport) part?

Comment: @DaniloCarvalho Sorry, I wasn't clear. By "method in question", I meant the nominally unmanaged method that's attempting to call `test()` in the console application that's compiled with the `/clr` option. However, I do not believe that that declaring the function with `__declspec(dllexport)` is sufficient to make it unmanaged, but maybe that depends on the compiler version?